# my $results are not working in my php functions [SOLVED]

Tags: php, function

```
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
    $result;
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrepeat)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

It keeps returning this  Undefined variable '$result'.
Below is the full error message. I also add an image.
[{
"resource": "/c:/xampp/htdocs/FeedCalculator/includes/functions.inc.php",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#1",
"code": "1008",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Undefined variable '$result'.",
"source": "intelephense",
"startLineNumber": 4,
"startColumn": 5,
"endLineNumber": 4,
"endColumn": 12
}]

The code and error as seen in vs

Thanks, it is working now. I got rid of the first $result and did some other minor tweaks. Its been 3 days so I do not remember, but thank you for being helpful!

Comment: That code wouldn't throw "undefined variable" for the `$result` variable. Post the complete error message and check what file and line it's in and point out the line that's causing it. _Side note:_ You can replace all the code inside that function with one line: `return empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrepeat);`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73671763/edit) your question to include all necessary information instead of in comments.

Comment: Please mark your question as solved. From your edit I'd say that Fido_de07 answer is it. This will also help future users (we just had a visitor). Best!

Answer (score 1):

the code looks correct for me (and is working, ive tried it on localhost with PHP8). Which PHP Version are you using?

Maybe try this:

```
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrepeat)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\hp>php -v
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 11 2022 08:55:59) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                       
This version 8.1